# Update list of items in c#

Tags: c#, linq, list, updates

I would like to know if you can suggest me an efficient way to update a list of items in c#. Here is a generic example:

If CurrentList is

```
[ {Id: 154, Name: "George", Salary: 10 000}
  {Id: 233, Name: "Alice", Salary: 10 000}]
```

And NewList is

```
[ {Id: 154, Name: "George", Salary: 25 000}
  {Id: 234, Name: "Bob", Salary: 10 000}]
```

Then the result should be:

```
[{Id: 154, Name: "George", Salary: 25 000} 
{Id: 234, Name: "Bob", Salary: 10 000} ]
```

I don't want just to clear the first one and use the values from the second one, but want to update the ones with the same ID, remove the ones that have been deleted and add any new ones.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is this WPF or windows forms, or just basic List<T> ?

Comment: If `Id` is a unique identifier then i'd consider using a `Dictionary<int, Employee>` etc.. instead. It will make lookups/adding/removing a lot easier

Comment: What have you tried? The obvious solution of looping through new list and updating items of CurrentList (or adding new ones) and then looping through current list and removing things not in new list would seem to work. Have you tried this?

Comment: What type are you using ? List<anonymous type> ?

Comment: why would you want to do this in the first place? the outcome would be the same thing as `NewList`

Comment: What is the problem with `CurrentList = NewList`?

Comment: I thought they'd be the same thing but potentially if anything is doing reference equality checks then your new and old objects would be different. I'm not sure I can think of situations where I'd be doing that but if the OP says it is required then presumably their situation is such that this is relevant.

Comment: @Matt probably other objects are holding a reference to the 'old' objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something like this:  (for ordinairy lists)

```
// the current list
var currentList = new List<Employee>();
currentList.Add(new Employee { Id = 154, Name = "George", Salary = 10000 });
currentList.Add(new Employee { Id = 233, Name = "Alice", Salary = 10000 });

// new list
var newList = new List<Employee>();
newList.Add(new Employee { Id = 154, Name = "George", Salary = 25000 });
newList.Add(new Employee { Id = 234, Name = "Bob", Salary = 10000 });

// clean up
foreach (var oldEmployee in currentList.ToArray())
    if (!newList.Any(item => oldEmployee.Id == item.Id))
        currentList.Remove(oldEmployee);

// check if the new item is found within the currentlist. 
// If so? update it's values else add the object.
foreach (var newEmployee in newList)
{
    var oldEmployee = currentList.FirstOrDefault(item => item.Id == newEmployee.Id);
    if (oldEmployee == null)
    {
        // add
        currentList.Add(newEmployee);
    }
    else
    {
        // modify
        oldEmployee.Name = newEmployee.Name;
        oldEmployee.Salary = newEmployee.Salary;
    }
}
```

---

You can speed it up, using dictionaries, but that's not your question (for now)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with use of for loop and Linq expression:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < NewList.Count; i++)
        {
            var record = CurrentList.FirstOrDefault(item => item.Id == NewList[i].Id);
            if (record == null) { CurrentList.Add(NewList[i]); }
            else { record.Id = NewList[i].Id; record.Name = NewList[i].Name; record.Salary = NewList[i].Salary; }
        }

        CurrentList.RemoveAll(item => NewList.FirstOrDefault(item2 => item2.Id == item.Id) == null);
```

Example of usage:
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPkQ1.png)

Comment: Will there anything be removed? Because the objects that are missing from the `CurrentList` and new in the `NewList` are added before the removal. So all `Id's` will be present within the `CurrentList`.

Comment: Only those objects are deleted which ids are in CurrentList but are not found in NewList (so FirstOrDefault() method for these objects will return null)... Take a look at picture... In our case Michael was deleted because object with id 305 was not found in NewList

Answer (score 0):

A LINQ'y version wrapped in an extension method, could modified to be generic if 'Id' is on a interface of some sort.

The merge Action could potentially be a Merge() method on entity objects such as employee but I chose to use a delegate here .

```
public class Tests
{
    [Test]
    public void MergeSpike()
    {
        // the current list
        var currentList = new List<Employee>();
        currentList.Add(new Employee { Id = 154, Name = "George", Salary = 10000 });
        currentList.Add(new Employee { Id = 233, Name = "Alice", Salary = 10000 });

        // new list
        var newList = new List<Employee>();
        newList.Add(new Employee { Id = 154, Name = "George", Salary = 25000 });
        newList.Add(new Employee { Id = 234, Name = "Bob", Salary = 30000 });

        currentList.Merge(newList, (o, n) =>
        {
            if(o.Id != n.Id) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Attempt to merge on mismatched IDs");
            o.Name = n.Name;
            o.Salary = n.Salary;
        });


        Assert.That(currentList.Count(), Is.EqualTo(2));
        Assert.That(currentList.First(c => c.Id == 154).Salary, Is.EqualTo(25000));
        Assert.That(currentList.Any(c => c.Id == 233), Is.False);
        Assert.That(currentList.First(c => c.Id == 234).Salary, Is.EqualTo(30000));


    }
}

public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Salary { get; set; }
}

public static class EmployeeListExtensions
{
    public static void Merge(this List<Employee> currentList, IEnumerable<Employee> newList, Action<Employee, Employee> merge)
    {
        // Updates
        currentList.Where(e => newList.Any(n => n.Id == e.Id))
            .ToList().ForEach(e => merge(e, newList.First(n1 => n1.Id == e.Id)));

        // Deletes
        var remove = currentList.Where(cl => newList.All(nl => cl.Id != nl.Id)).ToList();
        currentList.RemoveAll(e => remove.Any(r => r.Id == e.Id));

        // Inserts
        currentList.AddRange(newList.Where(nl => currentList.Any(c => c.Id != nl.Id)));
    }
}
```